# How to remove characters from a matching string?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to remove spaces from a list of phone numbers. The phone numbers are in the following format: "+33 x xx xx xx xx" most of the time (quotes included). Spaces can be placed differently.

In notepad++, my "Find what:" field looks like this, and effectively matches every phone number encountered: `"\Q+\E[0-9 ]+"`. But I don't understand how to remove a part of it (the spaces).

I thought about doing it in two steps: first selecting the results of a search with the matching pattern above, and then doing a replacement with the "In selection" checkbox ticked, but I can't find how to select all search results at once.

Comment: Does the text contain anything other than the phone numbers? Is searching for " " and replacing it with "" not an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'simple' way is to use capture groups for each group of numbers. For a fixed format, that works well. Find:

```
"\+33 ([0-9]) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2})"
```

And replace with:

```
"+33$1$2$3$4"
```

---

The other way is a bit more flexible, but at the same time, can be a bit confusing, since it uses the `\G` anchor which is not so common, with the `\K` anchor, which might be even less common:

```
(?:"\+33|\G)[^\s"]*\K
```

(There is a space at the end) And replace with nothing.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS5sH5)

```
(?:          # Begin group
  "\+33      # Match "+33
|            # OR
  (?!^)\G    # At the end of the previous match (and exclude start of lines)
)            # End group
[^\s"]*      # Any non-space or quote characters
\K           # Reset the match
             # Match a space
```

Both `\G` and `\K` aren't available on some earlier versions of Notepad++. I don't remember exactly when they were introduced, but they work on v6.5.2.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But i don't understand some things: what is the point of creating a group? And what's the difference between `(?:` and `(:` ? Also, I don't understand the role of `\G`.

Comment: @Cutter It will be too long to explain in a comment, but here are potentially useful links: [`\G`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21972213/1578604) and [`(?: ... )`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/1578604)